# How can I get calls for the interview without experience?

Tags: software-industry, job-search

There are a number of coding practice websites that allow users to solve coding challenges.

E.g., Excersim, Codeleet, BeeCrowd, etc.

Suppose, I have profiles on those sites and I provide links in my CV.

If I show the employers that I solved a lot of problems of various kinds and I have a pretty solid reputation on those sites, will the employers be attracted?

If **not**, How can I get calls for the interview without experience?

Comment: VTC as opinion based. And my opinion is that no one will even look at it once.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, then, how do employers decide whom to call for an interview?

Comment: References >> actual experience >>>>> reading tea leaves. More or less that's it.

Comment: All of the jobs I've ever gotten have been the traditional submit a resume, usually with a follow up quick phone call to make sure I'm legit, and then an in-person (or video) interview.

Comment: This is offtopic, but if you have no experience but lots of time and want to get into software dev, it was never easier than it is now - simply contribute meaningfully to open source. That's how you gain both reference and experience.

Comment: It's doubtful to me that anyone on the front lines of reviewing candidates would look at those sites and it's even more doubtful to me that they would give them any serious weight and consideration if they did look at them.

Comment: I always find it weird when people suggest that beginners should contribute to open source. Writing open source code is hard. And since the team is doing it for free, they usually don't have time to mentor/handhold beginners.
I've never heard of a beginner that successfully contributed to an open source project (via coding).

Comment: There are groups who deliberately flag some work items as good ones for beginners to get started with and otherwise try to encourage participation. They do, however, generally assume skill level above rank beginner. That doesn't necessarily mean years of professional experience. An advanced student should have an adequate amount of skill to start contributing, if the group is organized enough to use them or they're dedicated enough to bootstrap themselves and start submitting proposed fixes for open issues.

Comment: Or, given that this is a grad student, write something or some things seriously useful on your own, showing your best coding/testing/documentation skills -- either tools or  educational material or both --post it as your own open source project(s), try the publicize it and get an initial user base, grow it from there. That's how most OS starts, one person with something valuable to share with the world. Of course that's not easy; that's why it is worthwhile, and that's why it impresses when chugging through rote code exercises may not.

Comment: See the coding stacks for advice on getting started in OS, though; this is sliding off topic.

Comment: Do you have some sort of academic qualification?

Comment: @DJClayworth, Yes. I have BSc + MSc in IT. Now, I am a Ph.D. student. However, I have some years of job-gap due to some life-struggle.

Comment: The entry path for someone with a PhD is very different for someone without one. The best way is to find a company for which your area of expertise is relevant, and send them a detailed resume describing your thesis work.

Comment: @user366312 What is the general topic of your PhD? Are you producing code as part of your PhD?

Comment: Then I would emphasise those factors in your CV. And not mention these coding challenge sites at all.

Comment: @JackAidley, Apparently nothing is working. It seems to me that I need to leave this current country as soon as I finish my Ph.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coders do a lot more than solve coding problems.

They need to be aware of the industry in which they are working, they need to be aware of the quirks and benefits of the specific technologies being used on their project.

They need to understand how to turn requirements into algorithms and how to test those algorithms, where are the edge-cases etc.  And all this while coding within an architecture and code-base that is already in place.

Good team members need to be able to work with their colleagues, day after day, often in high-stress situations and maintain their motivation to get the product delivered.

When I'm reading through CVs, even for the most junior positions, I'm looking for signs that the candidate can develop to a stage where they can do all of the stuff above: can they keep down a job, can they work with other people, can they learn the technologies and industry domain?

My advice is:

- Focus on the employer's business. Understand that what employers are looking for is someone who can help to ship a product so that they can make a profit.
- Do something that involves working with other people; team    sports,
  voluntary work etc. or open source projects -  Dimitar Spasovski
  makes a good point about beginners contributing to open source
  coding projects, but I bet there are lots that are crying out for
  testers documenation writers etc.
- Keep on with the coding problems; they will improve your skills.
- Get a nine-to-five job, any job, to show that you can be relied on
  to turn up (I'm guessing that your PhD work will make this difficult).

Answer (score 6):

> How can I get calls for the interview without experience?

Apply for jobs that specify "No experience necessary" or at least apply for entry-level jobs.

Comment: This. Apply for jobs that expect to hire recent graduates and are only looking for the level of experience you actually have. If you think you can do better, convince them if that once you have your foot in the door. Start *building* the job history.

Answer (score 2):

This is often a chicken-and-egg scenario for many people new to the employment world.

How much stock a hiring manager will put in coding test sites is such a wild variable that it almost makes this question un-answerable (see the calls for 'too opinion based')

For me, I would consider those coding sites - but I'd put more stock in say whether you had a part-time job.

I care more about your *work ethic* than your skills and experience - because as an entry level worker (even if you have a degree) as far as I'm concerned, you have none.

Things you can do though, if you can't get an interview - look at places like Fivver (I think) where people submit requests for work, with a dollar value. Now, I've not used it and from what I understand there is a lot of shall we say 'low-balling' - but a completed, delivered coding project for a paying customer is worth 20 times what a code challenge website is worth to me.

Internship at a company - even an unpaid one, "I'm looking for work experience as a Software Dev" - some companies might have some odd-job code projects that they don't have the manpower to deal with at a full Software Dev rate, but a recent graduate could probably tackle. Even better if it is a paid internship with the possibility of a full-time role after completion.

I trust this gives some ideas - essentially, when you have no experience - what I want to know is that you will work hard and have a willingness to learn. Everything else happens with time.

Comment: I am a victim of coordinated racism.

Comment: @user366312 Only if you believe you are. If you stop acting like a Victim, you'll find people stop treating you like a Victim.

Comment: Tell me what is the meaning of not getting any calls for entry-level or no-experience jobs when I am a PhD student and working in Python, C++, and Rust?

Comment: @user366312 - because you are a Dime-a-dozen with nothing that demonstrates to an employer that you are worth investing **my time** and **my money** into. I've been in your position, despite being as white as they come, in a majority white country. It's not racism. Do you have a part-time job? Do you engage in any volunteer work? Are you doing something that shows me you have a good work ethic and are likely to be a wise investment for my company? If not, then I'll move onto someone who is. This may come across as Harsh, but it's the reality of work.

Comment: *Do you have a part-time job?* --- like KFC, McDonalds?

Comment: @user366312: all else being equal, any job is better than none.

Comment: How the hell did racism came into this ?

Comment: @Itération122442 - I suspect that the OP thought that his not getting any call backs was due to his Race - however as per my comment, it can easily be explained by his position, without race being a factor.

Comment: @Itération122442, Coz, I never even got any internship opportunity. Does an internship also require experience? I inquired about it on Quora and other forums and found that it is a very common issue in Europe.

Comment: @TheDemonLord, I did an experiment by changing my name and country of origin and got an interview offer. How do you explain that?

Comment: @user366312 - That's often cited as 'Racism' - my experience is more to do with cultural issues. I'm not justifying it, I'm just saying I dispute it's due to 'race' specifically.

Comment: Could be coincidence. Could be prejudice. Could be because you aren't making it clear that you are already living in and able to work in the country where the job is. (If you aren't, then you're unlikely to be considered at this skill level.)

Comment: @keshlam, *Could be because you aren't making it clear that you are 
already living in and able to work in the country where the job is.* --- unless they are unable to read my correspondence address and phone number.

Comment: That means you're in the country. It doesn't necessarily mean you have a work permit. I agree that they shouldn't be making assumptions about that, but a preemptive statement in your application might not hurt

Comment: @keshlam, *It doesn't necessarily mean you have a work permit.* --- My CV explicitly tells that I have a work permit. Students can work full-time in this country. I have 3 years residence permit.

Comment: OK. Still not proof you're being discriminated against, but suggestive. But seriously, what can you do about it if you are? There's no good way to prove it from a single sample, and I don't see a good way to counter it on an individual basis.

Comment: Asking for a part time Job from someone doing a PhD is _insane_. Getting a PhD is far better proof of a work ethic than any part time job.